# Postgres AVG function is not working with To_char function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am newbie in Postgres, I want to calculate the average 'duration' and converting it into a format like hh:mm:ss, in Postgres but when I am using the below query getting the error

> ERROR:  function avg(text) does not exist.

HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."

My query is

```
select processname, 
       count(processinstanceid), 
       avg(TO_CHAR((duration/1000 || 'seconds')::interval, 'HH24:MI:SS')) 
from processinstancelog 
group by processname 
order by processname asc
```

However, the same function I am using to calculate the min and max
'duration' and it's working. I have attached the screenshot as well.

```
select processname, 
       count(processinstanceid), min(TO_CHAR((duration/1000 || 'seconds')::interval, 'HH24:MI:SS')), 
       max(TO_CHAR((duration/1000 || 'seconds')::interval, 'HH24:MI:SS')),
from processinstancelog
group by processname
order by processname asc
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What is `duration`?

Comment: Duration is Bigint column in the database. and showing the integer values.
Desired result : i want to calculate the average duration in the format like hh:mm:ss together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to format the output, apply the `to_char()` **after** calculating the average:

```
select processname, 
       count(processinstanceid), 
       to_char(make_interval(secs => avg(duration/1000.0)), 'HH24:MI:SS')
from processinstancelog 
group by processname 
order by processname asc
```

`make_interval(secs => avg(duration/1000.0))` converts the result of the `avg()` function to an interval (in seconds). The result of that is then formatted using `to_char()`.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres is pretty flexible about intervals -- and allows averaging them.  So, if `duration` is measured in seconds, you can use:

```
select avg(duration * interval '1 second')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5a68dab4f40c1224cb2a84565a598feb) is a db<>fiddle that illustrates different possibilities.

Comment: I have used the suggested query this giving me the below result
processname   avg  
A   07:35:15.66667
B   4855:27:36.6 
C   576:42:42.5 
The result I am expecting should be like below
processname   avg  
A   07:35:15
B   00:00:00 
C   00:00:00 
I'm redefining for the understanding that I have a (Bigint)column in DB named as duration and showing the integers values only like 232424.3223(in ms default) when I am using the simple AVG (duration) function.
The expected result I want is the average duration in Hours, Minutes, and seconds (HH:MI:SS)